# Syntax error in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm trying to do a command that gather stats of tables that has more than 10 million rows. Right now only one table has, but i want the command to execute the gathering to more tables as soon as they reach 10 million rows.

Right now I have this command, but i can't find out what is wrong that is preventing it of running ok. I have ~ok~ sql skills, but almost *zero* experience with Oracle PL SQL.

Can someone point me a direction? Tks in advance.

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR t1 is
     select table_name from dba_tables where owner='SAPIENS_TESTE' and num_rows > 10000000;
BEGIN
 OPEN t1
 FOR t IN t1 LOOP
    EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME => 'SAPIENS_TESTE', TABNAME => '||t.table_name||', partname => NULL, granularity => 'GLOBAL', CASCADE => TRUE, method_opt => 'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUTO');
 END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: What's `'||t.table_name||'` for? Cargo cult?

Comment: @mustaccio Anything is possible. I have seen developers using code like this in loops as above: `execute immediate 'exec DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(''' || t.owner || ''',''' || t.table_name || ''')';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR t1 is
     select table_name from dba_tables where owner='SAPIENS_TESTE' and num_rows > 10000000;
BEGIN
 FOR t IN t1 LOOP
    DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME => 'SAPIENS_TESTE', TABNAME => t.table_name, partname => NULL, granularity => 'GLOBAL', CASCADE => TRUE, method_opt => 'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUTO');
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi Balazs. I understood the changes. Is very obvious. Thank you very much.